# How might I write a latin phrase for swapping bodies?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, translation-check, medieval-latin

Putting together a small literary piece where an item is inscribed with a Latin phrase that hints that it can be used to swap bodies (or minds, depending, I suppose, on your perspective) with another person. After much fiddling with Google translate, I initially settled on *Commutationem Corporum*. However, it's a mouthful.

After more fiddling, I am considering *Corpus Vorto*. Are either of these acceptable? Is there something that might work better?

I prefer medieval Latin, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just to make sure, you want a _description_ of the item, not some kind of spell, right?

Comment: @Rafael, Right. Not looking for a spell. Just an inscription that indicates that the item can be used for swapping bodies. In English it might say, "Body Changer", or "Exchanges Your Body with Someone Else" or whatever. Would like it to be short and sweet as Corpus Vorto seems to be.

Comment: I think the answers you have gotten so far are really good.  You can't swipe the opening line of Ovid's *Metamorphoses* as is since you need a slightly different meaning, but using a compound of *muto* is first rate, to echo *in nova ... mutatas .... formas corpora*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Commūtātiōnem Corporum* = "exchange of bodies", a noun phrase, in the accusative case.

*Corpus Vortō* = either "I change a body" or "I rotate a body", a verb phrase.

---

I would go with first a noun in the accusative case for "body/bodies", then a verb in the first person singular meaning "I change".

For the noun you could choose from *corpus* "a body", *corporēs* "bodies", *imāginem* "a shape", *imāginēs* "shapes", *formam* "appearance", *formās* "appearances".

For the verb you could choose from *commūtō* "I exchange", *mūtō* "I change", *vertō*/*vortō* "I turn".

You can mix and match these freely, but my vote is for *imāginēs commūtō*, "I exchange shapes". If you want something longer you could turn it into a sentence, *imāginēs hominum inter sēsē commūtō* "I change the forms of people back and forth", but given your comments I'm assuming you want something short and sweet.

---

You can include the marks on top of the vowels, or leave them off, at your preference. They represent a difference in sound that was important in Classical times but disappeared in later Latin. If this is meant to be Mediaeval, definitely leave them off.

Comment: Thanks @Draconis. I will probably go with _Commuto Corpores_.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Corporēs Commūtō (or even Corporēs Excambiō)? Basically it would mean *bodies exchange* or *exchange bodies*.

- *Corpus* is "body", but *Corporēs* is "bodies".
- *Commūtō* is Latin from *con-* "with, together" +‎ *mūtō* “change, alter” = 1. "I change or alter entirely; modify, correct, reform,
  transform." 2. "I exchange something with another, change, barter,
  interchange, replace, substitute, traffic."
- *Excambiō* is from Latin *ex* "out of" with Late Latin *cambiō* "change" = "exchange" or "I exchange".

Maybe Excambiō Corporēs would be better? As it would basically mean "I exchange bodies".

Comment: Welcome to the site! As *corpus* is a neuter, you might want *corpora* instead of *corpores*. You can always edit your answer, at least if you register your account.

Comment: Is *excambio* an actual Latin word? *Cambio* should carry the same meaning and is actually attested; however, it seems to be a rare word from mercantile jargon.